# How can I cast a Number to BigInt in dataweave in Mule 4?

Tags: sql-server, mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, raml

I want to insert records to a database but I´m getting this error

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to BIGINT is unsupported.
Element               : (None)
Element DSL           : (None)
Error type            : DB:QUERY_EXECUTION
FlowStack             : (None)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Input Values

```
[{
    claclientecuenta: vars.claclientecuenta,
    marca: payload.marca,
    nombre: payload.nombre,
    estatusid: payload.estatusid
}]
```

-QUERY-

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Marca 
VALUES (:claclientecuenta,:marca,:nombre, :estatusid);
```

I defined the RAML as Number but in the database is defined as BigInt

Do you have any idea in how to solve it?

I´ve searched for a long time but I don´t find in the documentation what I need or other solutions

Comment: Did you try passing the Java class in the class property of the coercion that the JDBC driver requites? https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-types-coercion#properties-for-type-coercion

Comment: could you give me an expample with bigint ? please

Comment: The problem might not be exactly what you are supposing. Please share the database operation and the input values. Also share the complete error from the log rather than just the message. Kindly edit the question with the data.

Comment: I already gave more information,

Comment: What is the field that causes the error and what is its input value and data type?

Comment: clacuentacliente  is the field :(

Comment: Then  what value and data type vars.claclientecuenta contains?

Comment: Also what version of Mule 4 and the Database connector are you using?